# Passing a filename into a script as an argument. No such file or directory

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I'm relatively new to shell scripting and I've been stuck on this error for a couple days now. I'm trying to read in the contents of a file containing a list of strings and numbers, format it, and output the number of numbers below 50.

All the commands work when typed into the shell, however; in the script when I try and pass the filename in as an argument I keep getting a "No such file or directory" error.

Here is the function in question:

```
 belowFifty(){
    count=0
    numbers=`cut -d : -f 3 < "$2"` #here is where the error occurs
    for num in $numbers
    do
      if ((num<50));
      then
      count=$((count+1))
      fi
    done
    echo $count
}
```

edit: sorry I forgot to mention the script does a couple things. $1 is the option, $2 is the file. I'm calling it like so:

```
./script.sh m filename
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
${2? 2 arguments are required to function belowFifty}
numbers=$( cut -d : -f 3 < $2 )
```

I suspect the problem is that you are calling the function
and not specifying the 2nd argument.  Within the function,
$2 is the argument passed to the function, and not the argument
passed to the main script.

Comment: Thank you! I wasn't aware the functions take their own set of arguments and was using the argument passed into the script. This solved my problem!

Answer (score 0):

You specify `"$2"`; what's in the `"$1"` that's passed to the function and ignored?  My strong suspicion is that you are trying to open the file with an empty string as the name, and there is no such file - hence the error message.  The corollary is that you probably intended to reference `"$1"`.
If so, you should probably write:

```
numbers=$(cut -d : -f 3 < "$1")
```

The back-tick notation should usually be avoided in favour of `$(...)`.

Comment: sorry, please see my edit. My fault for not being clear. I tried the $(...) notation as well and I'm still getting the same error.